# Did the Fifth Doctor ever save the universe using a kettle and some string?

Tags: doctor-who, episode-identification

In the minisode *Time Crash* ([available in full on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4I76p1cZbq4)), the Tenth Doctor says to the Fifth Doctor:

> Oh no, of course! You mostly went hands free, didn't you? Like 'eh, I'm the Doctor, I can save the universe using a kettle and some string, and look at me, I'm wearing a vegetable'.

This refers to the fact that the Fifth Doctor [didn't use a sonic screwdriver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonic_screwdriver#1968.E2.80.931982.2C_1996) for most of his tenure on the show. But is it a reference to anything more specific? **Is there actually a Fifth Doctor episode where he saves the universe using "a kettle and some string"**, or is Ten just inventing a random example of everyday household objects?

Comment: I'm more interested about the "wearing a vegetable" part. +1 to anyone who provides pictures :D

Comment: @Gallifreyan [Do I get a +1](http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/tardis/images/3/38/CeleryClose.jpg)?

Comment: @Randal'Thor - That's *holding*, not wearing

Comment: This is [wearing](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/eb/Fifth_Doctor.jpg).

Comment: @Valorum Now that's just lazy. I found a picture with a close-up of the vegetable :-)

Comment: I'd +1, but I've hit both my post and comment daily vote limit :(

Comment: https://www.etsy.com/listing/87071694/2-inch-5th-doctor-button-string-tea

Comment: I think 10 was just being sarcastic.  While 5 did do a lot of clever stuff, I can't find any episode in which a kettle and string were used together.

Comment: @Gallifreyan - he had that celery stick on his lapel to warn him about some gas he was allergic to https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/eb/Fifth_Doctor.jpg

Comment: The third Doctor once made a [time flow analog](http://38.media.tumblr.com/5916bacf35f321c4ee857dd8902ef271/tumblr_mjrmb18msi1qcwhkeo1_500.gif) on screen (and it's about as silly as it looks). The fifth used a cricket ball as propellant once, but I think it was more a dig about being sonic-less.

Comment: [Here is a picture of the Fifth Doctor wearing celery](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/tardis/images/7/7f/Fivedoctors.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20170613044019)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such episode.  It's possible that it might have occurred in some extended universe material, but it seems like just a funny turn of phrase.